# Does BeanPostProcessor override the initializing bean notification?

Tags: spring

I was experimenting Spring's BeanPostProcessor, BeanFactoryPostProcessor, Initializing bean , destroy bean.

I'm confused with these notification concepts.

I created a simple bean implementing Initi*Bean, Disposable bean. And also registered sample post processor , factoryPostprocessor. And added sysout in all the interface methods.

I created AbstractApplicationContext and registered shutdown hooks as well.

When i ran the app, i see BeanFactoryProcessor method prints, AfterProperties method, and then destroy method called. I dont see "initializing bean" called..

Does BeanPostProcessor override the initializing bean notification?

Kindly explain.

Comment: Please show a complete example that demonstrates the behavior you are describing.

Comment: 1) Employee bean implements InitializingBean, disposable bean
2) SampleBeanPostProcessor implements BeanpostProcessor
3) SampleBeanFactoryBeanPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor.

AbstractAPplication context intialized with AnnotationConfiurer.
context registered with shutdown hooks. Retrieved Employee bean and context is closed..

Comment: I see `afterPropertiesSet` invoked just fine with Spring 4x.

Comment: `afterPropertiesSet` is the `InitializingBean` method.

Comment: i used 4.1.6. This is what printing.. 
postProcessBeanFactory:
postProcessBeforeInitialization:
destroy

Comment: Ok, so provide a complete example, with code and everything, because this works fine for me.

Comment: If is disable postprocessor, afterProperties set is coming..

Comment: Are you returning `null` or the bean from your `BeanPostProcessor` methods?

Comment: https://github.com/manojp1988/Learning/tree/Learning/SpringSample

Comment: Add that to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning `null` in both your `BeanPostProcessor` methods. This causes Spring to think you don't want any further processing on that bean, including initializing through `InitializingBean`.

Just return the original bean you receive (in both methods)

```
@Override
public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String arg1) throws BeansException {
    System.out.println("postProcessAfterInitialization");
    return bean;
}
```

since you don't want to process it.